# Rearranging matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have a question in one of my assignments that is as follows:

Find the matrix *A* (in terms of *B*,*C*, and *D*) if

$(2B^{-1}A^{-1}C)^{-1} = D$

Possible options for answer are as follows:

A.) $2BDC$

B.) $\frac{1}{2}B^{-1}DC $

C.) $\frac{1}{2}BDC$

D.) $2CDB^{-1}$

E.) $\frac{1}{2}CDB $

F.) $2CDB$

G.) $\frac{1}{2}CDB^{-1} $

H.) $2B^{-1}DC $

So, my solution was:

$(2B^{-1}A^{-1}C)^{-1} = D$

$I = (2B^{-1} A^{-1}C) D $

$ IA = (2B^{-1} C) D$

$A = 2B^{-1}CD$

My answer is obviously not listed...any ideas? I mean mine is close in to D, but obviously multiplication order matters with matrices so its wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is here $IA = (2B^{-1} C) D$. Why did $A$ go to the other side ?

The correct way to do it:

Use $(X_1X_2X_3)^{-1} = X_3^{-1}X_2^{-1}X_1^{-1}$ if the three matrices are square of course (and invertible).
\begin{equation}
 (2B^{-1}A^{-1}C)^{-1} = D
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{2} C^{-1}AB = D
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 C^{-1}AB = 2D
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 AB = 2CD
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 A = 2CDB^{-1}
\end{equation}
So $D$ is one choice.

Comment: Argh, I am kicking myself. I think i need to sleep! Thank you!

Comment: At first I've made a mistake with the factor 2, corected after your solution!

Comment: ah yes i see @gimusi

Answer (score 1):

Use that

$$(2B^{-1}A^{-1}C)^{-1} =\frac12C^{-1}AB= D \implies C^{-1}AB=2 D \implies CC^{-1}ABB^{-1}=2 CDB^{-1} $$